# Transfer mouse events on the masked region of a QWidget to it's parent

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, masking

I have a `QMainWindow` which contains a circular `QWidget` inside it. In order to have a circular shaped `QWidget` I am making use of `QWidget::setMask`. The intended behaviour of the application on mouse press is  inside the MainWindow depends on the region on which mouse is pressed.

```
class MyMainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MyMainWindow():QMainWindow()
    {

    }
    void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
    {
        qDebug()<<"Clicked on MainWindow";
    }
};

class CircularWidget: public QWidget
{
public:
    CircularWidget( QWidget * parent ):QWidget( parent )
    {

    }
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event)
    {
        QRegion circularMask( QRect( pos(), size() ), QRegion::Ellipse );
        setMask( circularMask );
        setStyleSheet("background-color:black;");
        QWidget::paintEvent( event );
    }
    void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
    {
        qDebug()<<"Clicked on Circular Widget";
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow w;
    w.resize( 400, 400 );

    CircularWidget circularWidget( &w );
    circularWidget.show();

    w.setCentralWidget( &circularWidget );
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Currently, when I click inside the circular region I get the event in my Widget. But all the mouse press events outside the circle are lost. I saw in the Qt Documentations that: `Masked widgets receive mouse events only on their visible portions`. Is there any way to transfer the other mouse click events (events on the grey region in the picture) to the parent widget?

Comment: So the CircularWidget covers whole main window? How do you place this widget in the main window?

Comment: I will have to resize it, But currently it covers the whole mainWindow. I just want all the mouse events that are made outside of the circle to be taken up by the mainwindow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you did not get mouse events in your `MyMainWindow` class is because in your main() function you create the main window object of class `QMainWindow` instead.
For handling the mouse click events on the circular widget I would use signal/slot mechanism here. I.e. let the circular widget emit a signal each time it is clicked. Any other receiver will handle it as its own. For example:

```
class MyMainWindow: public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
    [..]
public slots:
    void handleMouseClick(const QPoint &) {}
};

class CircularWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    [..]
    void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
    { emit mouseClicked(event->pos()); }
signals:
    void mouseClicked(const QPoint &);
};
```

And finally establish connection. With this in `MyMainWindow` class you will be able to handle mouse click events both from circular widget and main window itself.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MyMainWindow w; // <-------- This should be MyMainWindow instead of QMainWindow

    CircularWidget circularWidget( &w ); 
    w.setCentralWidget( &circularWidget );

    QObject::connect(&circularWidget, SIGNAL(mouseClicked(const QPoint &)),
                     &w, SLOT(handleMouseClick(const QPoint &));

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: But the mousepressevent of the circularWidget is not getting called when I click on the region outiside the circular mask. And it's also not calling the mousepressEvent of the mainWindow as well

Comment: @sajas, please look at my updated response. The problem is that you created QMainWindow object instead of creating MyMainWindow class object.

Comment: Oops. Missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Proper solution is reject mouse press event if pointer is outside of region so more or less it should look like this:

```
void mousePressEvent( QMouseEvent * event )
{
    QRegion circularMask( QRect( pos(), size() ), QRegion::Ellipse ); // it would be nice to make it a class field

    if (!circularMask.contains(event->pos()) {
        event->ignore();
    }
}
```

See [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmouseevent.html#details):

> A mouse event contains a special accept flag that indicates whether
>   the receiver wants the event. You should call ignore() if the mouse
>   event is not handled by your widget. A mouse event is propagated up
>   the parent widget chain until a widget accepts it with accept(), or an
>   event filter consumes it.